# Fatal Python error: Unable to start an older version of python in a conda virtual environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda

The Anaconda installed on my computer comes with Python 3.7.3. Because some packages I need to use require Python 3.5, I created a separate conda environment, specifying Python 3.5

`conda create -n env1 python=3.5`

After creating the environment, I activated it and tried to start Python

```
activate env1
python
```

But I got the following error:

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: can't initialize sys standard streams
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\io.py", line 52, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\abc.py", line 147
    print(f"Class: {cls.__module__}.{cls.__qualname__}", file=file)
                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I wonder what the issue is and how I can resolve it.

**EDIT**: Just in case this problem has to do with environment variables, below is a screenshot of the setup of the **PYTHONPATH** is below

[image]

Comment: try using `conda activate env1`

Comment: Still the same error~~

Comment: issue is related to the environment creation, maybe follow this [link](https://uoa-eresearch.github.io/eresearch-cookbook/recipe/2014/11/20/conda/) to create env, just create env by `conda create -n env1 anaconda`

Comment: @prashantrana: as I noted in my post, I specifically need Python 3.5 for some of the packages I use; otherwise, I would just stick to Python 3.7. I've created other virtual environments with Python 3.7 with no issue.

Comment: Try with `source activate <full_path of environment>` (before bin folder). After this see the output of `which python` and see where it points to.

Comment: @Alex i forgot to add python , `conda create -n env1 python=3.5 anaconda`

Comment: @prashantrana There is absolutely no reason to include `anaconda` in the installation. That would entail installing everything in Anaconda distribution. Completely unnecessary.

Comment: @merv I agree, and I actually did that before, to no avail

Comment: @Alex I'm not on Windows (so take it FWIW), but my `PYTHONPATH` environment variable is always empty, whether activated or no. I suspect that could be the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to clear the `PYTHONPATH` variable - it should be empty. I can confirm that I will get the exact same error if I do the following test:

```
conda create -n env1 python=3.5
conda activate env1
PYTHONPATH="/Users/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.7" python
```

which gives

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: can't initialize sys standard streams
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/io.py", line 52, in <module>
  File "/Users/user/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/abc.py", line 147
    print(f"Class: {cls.__module__}.{cls.__qualname__}", file=file)
                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Abort trap: 6
```

A simple test in your direction would be:

```
conda activate env1
PYTHONPATH="" python
```

or whatever the Windows equivalent of that is.

Comment: Wow! Removing those lines did do the trick! I will accept the answer in a day or two after some testing -- I want to make sure removing those lines won't have any other side effects.

Comment: @Alex yeah, that makes sense. I'm not familiar with the Windows Anaconda install settings, so definitely test. Although, I will say I'd expect many others would have hit this same error if Anaconda was setting `PYTHONPATH`.